# How to make an If Else on Excerpt Filter

Tags: functions, customization, filters, excerpt

Im trying to do an if/else on a custom excerpt filter in functions.php file but not having any luck. Heres what I have. What I am trying to do is customize one of the excerpts being generated. I need to have 'Watch Video' instead of the read more for one post. I tried wrapping that in an if (is_single('my page')) but it doesn't have any affect. Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated!

thanks!

```
function custom_excerpt($text) { 

  $excerpt = '' . strip_tags($text) . '<span class="readmore"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" rel="nofollow">Read More &raquo;</a></span>';

   return $excerpt;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt');
```

Comment: `is_single( 'my page' )` will return true if my page is a single post, even if you're not on 'my page', in the same way that is_building('house') will always return true, even if you're currently on a lake, you want to check that the current post is 'my page', not that 'my page' is a page

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be including the read more link in your excerpt, there's a different filter and system that takes care of that in the `the_content_more_link` filter, look at the documentation on the dev handbook for `the_excerpt` for an example

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'm using the the_excerpt() method not the_content() method. Which in the handbook has the link in there albeit I should of used what was in the HB. I must of got that piece of code off a website somewhere. I changed to what the HB has. So thanks for the advice! I'll give a shot. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution that seemed to work.**  Thanks Tom

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    $thePostID = $post->ID;
    if($thePostID == 1128) {
    return '...<a class="readmore" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .  '">Watch Video &raquo;</a>';
    } else {
    return '...<a class="readmore" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more &raquo;</a>';
    }
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```